# SharePoint 2013 document is not visible with read and contributor right, only visible with Full control

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, permissions

SharePoint 2013 document is not visible with read and contributor right, only visible with Full control:

We have implemented following activity:

1. Breakup permission of library
2. Provide Everyone with read access on library.
3. Given some user contributor and Full Control access right
4. In case person having full control only can see document

I have checked all the below option to check the issue:

1. Manage Files With No Checked In Version: Go to Library Settings and
   click the "Manage files which have no checked in version" link. If
   users have uploaded files but not checked them in, the users who
   uploaded the documents will be the only ones who can see them.
   Fortunately, the site owner can take ownership of checked out files,
   then check them in.
2. Version Access: Go to Library Settings and click the "Versioning
   Settings" link. If "Content Approval" is turned on, then only people
   with access to Approve items will be able to see unapproved items.
   Similarly, if "Create major and minor (draft) versions" is checked,
   double-check what the "Draft Item Security" is set to-- you probably
   want it to be "Any user who can read items" 3) Permissions: Finally,
   go to Permissions for this document library and confirm that there
   are no documents or folders with unique permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Even if versioning is turned off and check in / out is not required to edit, if there is required metadata that hasn't been filled in, the document won't be checked in and will not be visible to anyone other than the user who added the document. Ensure the user who added the document has completed any madaotry metadata and then checked the file in.

Comment: All the mandatory metadata are entered and also checked the file in. Currently user can see only his own upload file.

Comment: What version is the document at? It isn't clear whether you do have versioning turned on. Is the version of the document a 0.* ?

Comment: All the document at 1.0 version

Comment: Do users with contribute who have been given permissions directly (not through a group) not see other user's documents? Could it be "Everyone" access that isn't working as it should.

Comment: Yes I have checked in this way also, by adding directly as well as through group, I got the same issue.  Both contributor as well as Everyone are not able to see documents. Surprisingly when I created new library and uploaded document both are able to see all the uploaded documents in new library.

Comment: Does the problem library use any content types, document templates or custom forms? If you can't replicate the issue by copying the same steps on a different document library, the easy solution is obviously to create a new document library and put it down to a bug!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Philips, however I have many libraries containing lot of documents. It will takes at least 5-6 days..I am looking for better options.

Comment: This issue is resolved, its related with breaking inheritance permission and removing all the roles from the libraries. To fix it instead of removing all roles, I have removed groups...